# How to "redirect" Ubuntu desktop monitor to USB port?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors

Since this is actually hardware issue (USB port  usage ) , please accept my apology up front.
And the title is as best as I can put it.

In less technical talk:
I want to display my photo images on PC and same time on my projector.
In technical terms - display image , for editing , on PC and send
the image file to
projector
**USING USB port**

I can list the USB port (lsusb shows Sharp driver ??) connected to the projector - I assume now the system can communicate with the projector.

I did check (Ubuntu) "settings->displays" and it has no entry / option  for adding another monitor and  the USB port does not show up there..

The projector has few inputs "plugs" , however , I need to use the USB one - have no other suitable cables.

I am not looking for additional  hardware AKA no " check  e-bay..."

My guess is - is there a image processing / editing application which has an option to output both to system monitor and to the projector USING USB port ?

I am currently using "shotWell" for image editing , and it  has no option to redirect the images.

( Mrs Google  found one application which may have output options , but it is .exe - time to install "wine" rats...)

Any constructive suggestion / help , no AI please , will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the projector allows video over the USB connection?  The only thing I can remotely find about the USB port on a Sharp projector is that it can be used to interface the remote as a mouse to the computer, but nothing is showing that it can accept it as video.  In order for a projector to do video over the USB it would need its own video encoding built in.  https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/152117/sharp-notevision-xr-32x.html?page=16  But I don't even know if that is your projector model.